# Is it ok to force value on an input port in Systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have this SV code :

```
module m1 (input int a);
    always begin #1; force a=a+1; end
endmodule

module m ();
    int a;  
    m1 m1(a);
endmodule
```

Is this statement in above code valid `force a=a+1;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work in your simulator, however it is not recommended.

In the IEEE std 1800-2009 section 10.6 defines a force statement as a "procedural continuous assignment." There is an example in the LRM stating that if a value on the right hand side of the equation is changes, then it will force the new value to the right hand variable. In this case `a=a+1` should technically cause an infinite loop but likely does not because of a scheduling rule.

In general `force` should be used sparingly and be used in a test bench and behavioral modeling. Functional expressions are allowed with force however circular dependance needs to be avoided. Best to assign a constant expression with `force` is possible.

Comment: Will it be fine if I change `force a = a+1` to `force a = b+1` where b can be any other variable ?

Comment: Yes, so long as `a` is not in the sensitivity list that triggers an update on `b`. Be aware that if `b` changes at any time while the `force` is applied then `a` will update. At least according to the LRM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the behavior is well defined in this case.  Module m1 will see the forced value but the enclosing module will not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will be more helpful to me if you can quote IEEE std section number along with your answer.